# javascript Filter function is not working in IE 11 but working fine in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

Filter function is not working in IE 11 Edge but its working fine in Chrome
and Mozilla .I am working on below code

```
var data = $(".chartsValue text");

var filteredData=data.filter(function()
 { return $(this).css('font-weight') == 'bold';
 }).text();
```

I am getting the value in html like below

```
<g class="chartsValue" style="cursor:pointer;text-align:center;" transform="translate(101,10)">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="19" height="16" strokeWidth="0" fill="none" rx="0" ry="0">
</rect>
<text x="0.828125" zIndex="1" style="font-size:11;font-weight:bold;color:black;fill:black;" y="14">
6m
</text>
```

So, I need to fetch 6m value through style in IE Edge too

Comment: Have you tried using native objects as opposed to jQuery wrapped objects? There might be a bug in jQuery for IE11

Comment: Thanks @DanielCooke I believe $(this).css doesn't work in beltter way in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Guys for the quick response I solved this problem by using attribute property

```
var filteredData =data.filter(function()
{
    return $(this).attr('style').indexOf('bold') > -1;
}).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we can extract a `filter` function and iterate even through `NodeList` type with pure JavaScript:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('g.chartsValue text');

const filter = fn => x => Array.prototype.filter.call(x, fn);

const r = filter(e => e.style['font-weight'] === 'bold')(els).map(x => x.innerText)

console.log(r)
```

```html
<g class="chartsValue" style="cursor:pointer;text-align:center;" transform="translate(101,10)">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="19" height="16" strokeWidth="0" fill="none" rx="0" ry="0">
</rect>
<text x="0.828125" zIndex="1" style="font-size:11;font-weight:bold;color:black;fill:black;" y="14">
6m
</text>
</g>
```

Tested in Edge, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @wostex for the solution it helped but still I believe arrow doesn't support in IE.I have provided my solution .Please have a look

Comment: I've tested the code, it works in IE. If you don't like arrows - you can rewrite it to regular syntax. Anyway, it's up to you which approach you choose.

Comment: yeah not sure I am using on IEedge and in console only it is giving syntax error on second line

Comment: @user2147163 I can't reproduce it. If you rewrite into es5 syntax it'll be much more verbose than it is now, probably doesn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`.filter(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) returns a subset of elements based on your function. If you want to access the first element in the resulting subset you should use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) e.g.:

```
var data = $(".chartsValue text");

var filteredData = data.filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("font-weight") === "bold";
}).first().text();
```

If there are multiple elements in the resulting subset you can use [`.map(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) e.g.:

```
var data = $(".chartsValue text");

var filteredData = data.filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("font-weight") === "bold";
}).map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

*You might also want to trim the text you get back using [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) e.g.:* `.text().trim();`

Comment: @user2147163 If this code doesn't resolve the problem please consider posting more of yours, as it is quite difficult to know whether or not my answer will work for yours based on what you gave us.

Comment: Thanks @Daft I believe css property is not working in IE11 .Please check my answer which I provided

Comment: @user2147163 Does Internet Explorer render the content of the `text`-element as if it were bold? Because I suspect that Internet Explorer doesn't handle custom elements, and their style, as it should and thusly gives you the result that it hasn't process the `font-weight` of the css at all.

Comment: Yes @Daft it is possible .Please check my answer I used attribute property style and worked for me .So, I believe the previous line of code didn't throw any error but result was empty So, I am not sure what actually breaks

Comment: @user2147163 I've seen your answer but it answers a problem that you didn't introduce in your post and I thusly have not up-voted it, though I will if you decide to reformat both the question and the answer to reflect this fact. As for my intent on asking you if you could confirm whether Internet Explorer handles custom elements correctly: if it were indeed confirmed that, that was the case then I might have issued a bug at jQuery, and might have considered to help them resolve it so that `.css(propertyName)` does work as intended on custom elements.

Comment: @user2147163 I've just now taken note of the fact that you might be using SVG elements instead of custom elements in your code, am I correct to assume for hereon out? Because if that is the case then I might have found what causes your issue, based on a reproduction I've made.