# Count how many arrays have a value at nth place in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array :

```
var array = [['a','b','success'],['d','e','success'],['d','e','success']]
```

What's the best way to find how many arrays in this array have success as their 3rd value?

What I have tried already :

```
var counter = 0
for (var g = 0; g < array.length; ++g){
  row = array[g]
  if(row[2] === "success") {
    counter = counter + 1
  }
}
```

I am trying to make my Apps script run faster.

Comment: Your method is linear with respect to the input size. You're going to have to at least check every array's 3rd element to get an accurate count. So your method can't really be improved. Perhaps if you can check the arrays as they're inserted into the array may be one way around needing to iterate the entire array.

Comment: How do you know it's slow?  Just by visual inspection?  One thing you can do that might speed it up is change `==` to `===`, as the former will unnecessarily determine if a type conversion is necessary

Comment: can you quantify “very slow” - looks like a simple loop, very few insrictions, simple code access - can you check - typically this sort of thing is just a few milliseconds on most desktops - depending on the spec...

Comment: @CodeUniquely - I am trying to do this with GAS. Exploring the ways I can stay under the max execution limit.

Comment: @Dexygen - I have done the same. It was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: @eceo - if it ties up the thread for too long, you could consider breaking the array down into smaller sections using slice and calling the count inside a setTimeout with the slice and increment the count with the result of each function call. You are done when your slice position loads the last of the array

Comment: @eceo I edited my solution and added a more efficient (fast) way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` can be an efficient and elegant solution

```js
var array = [['a','b','success'],['d','e','success'],['d','e','success']];

var n = array.filter((el) => el[2] === "success").length;

console.log(n);
```

**Edit after @Harun Yilmaz answer's**

If it's speed that you are looking for, the simpler -> the better, as high order functions introduces a small overhead, that is negligible in small numbers, more becomes more and more heavy in bigger arrays.

This solution is the fastest i can think, as remove all the non-necessary parts from the computation (double faster than the original):

```
var counter = 0;
var l = data.length;
for (var g = 0; g < l; ++g){
  if(data[g][2] === "success") {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

[Performance test:](https://jsben.ch/bCO91)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to create a counter:

```
data.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (cur[2] === 'success') ,0);
```

Here's benchmark results for your, my and @Greedo's approach for an array of 10.000 length:
https://jsben.ch/UeMMR

Your approach seems to be the fastest way among these 3 approaches.

Hope this helps

Comment: can be shorter with a slight "creative usage" of type coercion: `data.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (cur[2] === 'success'), 0);`

Comment: Hi @HarunYilmaz, check my edited answer for a more efficient script

Comment: @Greedo I think the link to the test remains the same as this answer. You may want to have a look at it.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz you right, i forgot to generate the new URL. Now it is updated

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Greedo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62814773), but using ES5 syntax instead of ES6 syntax (also slightly easier to read):

```js
var array = [['a','b','success'],['d','e','success'],['d','e','success']];

var count = array .filter(function(value){
    return value[2] === 'success';
}).length

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score -2):

This is pure js without any builtin methods.

Because you can see  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734102/javascript-filter-function-is-not-working-in-ie-11-but-working-fine-in-chrome-an) that .filter on array doesn't support in all browsers.

```js
//this is your data
var array = [['a','b','success'],['d','e','success'],['d','e','fail']]

//method to check either data exist at place and match data with 3rd param {value} 

function count_place(array,place,value){
 var count = 0;   
  for (let i = 0 ; i< array.length; i++) {
    if ((typeof array[i][place] != 'undefined' && typeof value == 'undefined') ||  (typeof value != 'undefined' &&  array[i][place] == value)){
      count++; 
    }
  }
  return count; 
}
document.write("Input array ", JSON.stringify(array))

document.write("<br/>");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write("<br/>");
document.write('count_place(array,2)   =   ',count_place(array,2))
// output will be 3
document.write("<br/>");

document.write("count_place(array,2,'success')   =   ",count_place(array,2,'success'))
//output will be 2 
document.write("<br/>");

document.write("count_place(array,2,'fail')   =   ",count_place(array,2,'fail'))
document.write("<br/>");
//output will be 1
```

Comment: "*filter on array doesn't support in all browsers*" [it's supported in all browsers from IE9 onwards](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_filter). I doubt it's worth writing that code for all the IE 8 and below users - you can just polyfill the method.